# Can the "New tag confirmation" be turned on?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, editing

From [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214543)

> 2014-06-10: When moderators or users with the "create new tags" privilege attempt to create one or more new tags either while asking a question or during an edit [they are shown a confirmation dialog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233897) to reduce risk of tags created by mistake. This feature is enabled on a per-site basis.

Can the [New tag confirmation dialog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233897) be enabled for the blender exchange? I think that would be helpful, for some of the tag typos that come along. [Example question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/14334/revisions) *intoface*, not *interface*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done! [Oded](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/users/37/oded) activated it this morning.

Comment: thanks that should help